# how to get different Exit code like 2 or 3 from main in go language?

Tags: python, go, exit

How do I get the exit code 3 or any non zero except 1 from main? I am trying to execute one program but when I execute will get exit code 1 instead of 3. If I want to get exit code 3 what I need to do?
ex:

```
package main
import "os"
func main() {

    // Exit with status code.
    os.Exit(3)
}
```

I want to run go script through python script Please find the python script below :

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def console(cmd):
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    return (p.returncode, out, err)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = console('go build test.go')
    result = console('./test')
    result = console('echo $?')
    print 'returncode: %s' % result[0]
    print 'output: %s' % result[1]
    print 'error: %s' % result[2]
```

I want to record the exit status code in Python program which can be used further for other logic.

Comment: Are you executing the command from Go, and you want the exit code of that app? Or you run your command e.g. from a shell, and you want to see what code it exists with?

Comment: If you tried something, and it did not work, please post in detail what you did and how it failed. In this case you say you tried to execute your program and did not get the correct exit code. It will be much easier to help you if you then 1. Posted how you ran your code. 2. Posted how you tried to obtain the exit code after you ran your program.

Comment: You're using `go build`. This will just compile the binary and not run it. Use `go run`. Also, you usually don't want to use `shell=True` in Python's subprocess. It's completely unnecessary and may open you up to security problems.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using `go run` to execute. In this case the exit status is not available as your executable is not running in bash, `run` is executing it in a subprocess. To see the difference use `build` and execute them,

**Example**

```
$ go build test.go
$ ./test
$ echo $?
3
```

---

**Edit**

If you are using a python program, you need not run the `echo $?`. This will give you a wrong answer because this is executed in a different shell than the one that executed the `./test` command.

You can always read the exit status of the command from the `Popen.returncode`. The script can be modified as

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def console(cmd):
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    return (p.returncode, out, err)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = console('./test')
    print result
```

This would give

```
$ python test.py
(3, '', None)
```

Comment: I have added the sample python code which will be used for running and recording the exit code.

Comment: @Dhanshree I have added an edit to give an example of python. Hope it helps